# Что предпочтительнее: мультитабличное наследование или GenericRelation?

Tags: python, django

Делаю каталог (интернет-магазин) на Django (в силу определенных причин необходимо писать именно свой код, а не пользоваться готовыми решениями).

Возник вопрос - какую структуру БД выбрать для SEO полей (title, description, h1, url). Url должен быть уникален (может содержать "/" - поэтому даже SlugField не подойдет), все url'ы 1-го уровня вложенности (site.ru/my-category, site.ru/my-product и т.д. - но часть будет с "/" для совместимости)

С точки зрения ООП логичнее кажется использовать наследование:

```
class SeoFields(models.Model):
    ...
    url = models.CharField(blank=True, null=False, max_length=200, unique=True)

class Category(SeoFields):
    ...

class Product(SeoFields):
    ...
```

Однако все руководства (в частности, Two Scoops of Django) советуют избегать табличного наследования.

Можно сделать модель SeoFields абстрактной, но тогда мы лишимся автоматической проверки url на уникальность, и узнавать, что же нужно показать (товар/категорию/страницу и т.д.) будет сложнее (потребуется несколько запросов к БД).

Можно сделать без наследования - добавить GenericForeignKey к SeoFields. Но тогда это усложнит извлечение url для конкретного объекта (+1 запрос к базе).

**Вопрос**: какая схема БД в данном случае предпочтительна? Стоит ли в данном случае избегать табличного наследования, или оно здесь уместно?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, я бы проверял бы поле url на уникальность в методе save, используя пакет https://github.com/un33k/django-uuslug/ как-то так:

```
class SeoFields(models.Model):
    url = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = uuslug(self.name, instance=self)
        super(SeoFields, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Табличное наследование вполне можете применять, непонятно в чем проблема: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance Вообще, не нужно усложнять, где можно решить задачу более простыми методами. GenericForeignKey здесь не нужен.